# List item field not updating during workflow SPD 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a workflow that isn't updating the current list item when run.  I have tried using Set Field in Current Item Item and Update Item in Current Item, but neither will update the field.

Step 1 of my workflow is:

```
If Current Item:Status is empty
> Set Status to Pending Approval
> then Email Current Item:ApprovingManager
```

The email sends just fine, but the Status field will not update.  The workflow marks as complete and there are no errors in the workflow history.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work instead? I've had workflows that don't like Empty, some that don't like blank

`If Current Item:Status not equals approved`

`or Current Item:Status not equals Rejected`

`>Set Status to Pending Approval`

`>then Email Current Item:ApprovingManager`

My Status column is a choice column with choices of: Approved, Other, Rejected, Pending Approval

Comment: I have tried using "is Empty" and equals "", and both trigger the email, but it never updates the Status field.  I have also tried moving the email to before the Status update and that didn't fix it.

Comment: This is what worked for me: 'if Current Item:Status not equals Approved' 'or Current Item: Status not equals Rejected' '>Set Status to Pending Approval' '>then Email Current Item:ApprovingManager'

To be clear though, my Status column is a choice column with choices of: Approved, Other, Pending Approval, Rejected

Comment: I have changed the Status field to be a choice instead of single line of text, but that still doesn't fix it.  The If statement isn't the issue, it's the Set Status to Pending Approval line.  The email going to the Approving Manager is within the same if statement and is sent, but the status refuses to update.  It shouldn't be a permissions issue either, as I have Full Control on that list (along with the rest of the site).